# How can I ignore default property that Jackson added?

Tags: spring, jackson, rabbitmq

I'm using jackson for making JSON object. I found that jackson add default property automatically. I really don't need this field, How can I remove that?

this is my code that simplified.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"@id"})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, scope = CustomMessage.class)
public class SystemMessage {
     private String body;
     }
 }
```

Eventhoug I added JsonIgnoreProperties annotation, It is not removed. I think it is because "@id" is a default property.

> {"@id":1,"body":"hello"}

this is the message I got by rabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Id` is added because of the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation - see https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html where you can see that this is the default for the `property` field.

This annotation is used for parent-child relationships and especially when you have circular dependencies among your objects. So if this is not true for you, you can just omit this annotation